# android Edittext hint issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

My layout file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/page_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/label_background" >

        <com.olacabs.customer.model.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="54dp"
            android:background="@color/label_background"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/invite_email"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="22dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            custom:customFont="Roboto-Regular.ttf" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" >

        <com.olacabs.customer.model.TextViewPlus
            android:id="@+id/emailHint"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:text="@string/enter_your_friend_s_email_address"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@color/heading_text_color"
            custom:customFont="Roboto-Regular.ttf" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/errorText"
            style="@style/errorText"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:padding="10dp" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/emailText"
                style="@style/emailText"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:hint="@string/email_ids_separated_by_commas"
                android:imeOptions="actionGo" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.olacabs.customer.model.ButtonPlus
            android:id="@+id/inviteButton"
            style="@style/button_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/invite"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            custom:customFontButtonText="Roboto-Regular.ttf" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The activity looks like this  [image: Layout display]

However, I want the text `Use comma....` to be displayed at the top of the edit text rather than the center. I tried setting `gravity:top` but that didn't help. Also, as you can see, the whole of the hint is not displayed and some of it gets hidden (I want the rest to appear n the next line). How can I correct these two issues?

My `emailText` style is :

```
<style name="emailText" parent="android:Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:ems">10</item>
    <item name="android:inputType">textEmailAddress</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
    <item name="android:hint">Email</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#B8B8B8</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">45dp</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: `I tried setting gravity:top but that didn't help` -- it was still centered?

Comment: yes. It still looked exactly the same as the image

Comment: Does the next start from the top when you enter something in?

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto No, it starts from the center

Comment: Could you post `emailText` style?

Comment: @IlangoJ The button is not an issue. the styles are in different xml that I created

Comment: You have `android:layout_height` in your style and in your xml with different values. Try removing the one in the style.

Comment: @iturki I tried that but it does not make a difference, I'm think the value entered in the layout file overrides the one entered in the styles file

Comment: @IlangoJ I have added the emailText style to my post. I tried tweaking it but it made no difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that you forgot the `android:layout_width` tag. you you add this and the `android:gravity` it should work.

try this code:

```
        <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/round_corners" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/emailText"
                        style="@style/emailText"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:background="@android:color/white"
                        android:hint="@string/email_ids_separated_by_commas"
                        android:gravity="top"
                        android:imeOptions="actionGo"
                        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

                </LinearLayout>
```

result:

[image]

Edit:

changed `android:padding="10dp"` from wrapper to `android:layout_margin="10dp"` of the edittext

Comment: Ok. The hint now appears at the top but a part of the hint is still hidden. How to correct this?

Comment: I tried this but for me the second line never appears. The text continues on the first line

Comment: try without your custom syling, that is the only difference, I think its the width tag in the style which causes the problem.

Comment: I realized that the issue was with `<item name="android:inputType">textEmailAddress</item>`